# Convert iso 3166 Alpha 3 to Alpha 2 codes

Tags: iso, opayo

I am a developer who is creating an online shopping cart using SagePay. We are currently using a dataset of Alpha 3 ISO 3166 Country codes and Sage pay use Alpha 2 codes. 
Can you tell me if you can use Alpha 3 or is there a way to convert Alpha 3 to Alpha 2 codes using c#?
There is a function in .NET (CultureInfo) that can convert around 120 out of 276 countries but Countries such as Congo (COD) or even England (GBE) are not supported.
We could do a substring on the Alpha three to strip off the last character but alas Congo (COD) is converted to CD in Alpha 2 so this wouldn't work. There are a few other countries that are converted in a similar way.
Do you know a work around for this?
Jon

Comment: Can't help you with the conversion, but can confirm Sage Pay will only work with the Alpha 2 codes.